# How to make search bar responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I want to make my html/css search bar responsive for example iphone 11.
Search button drops down after hovering over it, when i open it from my phone.
Here's the link: https://irinachikviladze.github.io/
How can I make it responsive using CSS?

```html
 <div class="search-box">
        <input class="search-txt" type="text" name="" placeholder="Type to search">
        <a class="search-btn" href="#">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
        </a>
     </div>
```

Comment: Seems like there is a fixed width for the search box when hover, try to add @media break points or maybe set the width by vw instead of fixed value?
.search-box:hover > .search-txt {
    width: 240px;  // maybe 50vw here?
    padding: 0 6px;
}

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_media_query_breakpoints.asp

Comment: For the "opening" of the search bar you can use a `click` event. Adding a class with the style of the hover state, makes the `search-box` also clickable (so touchable on mobile). Otherwise with media queries you could constantly show the opened search bar on e.g. mobile, and on tablet and desktop you could show it like in your example

Answer (score 0):

Every HTML element has a default display value depending on what type of element it is. The default display value for most elements is block or inline.

So just overwrite the default `display` for your search box and set it to `flex` with `flex-direction: row;`

that's it.

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background:#e74c3c; 
 }
 .search-box{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: #34495e;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
 }
 .search-box:hover > .search-txt{
    width: 240px;
    
    padding: 0 6px;
    }
 .search-box:hover > .search-btn{
    background : white ;
    
    }
 .search-btn{
    color: #e74c3c;
    float: right;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background:#34495e;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    overflow: hidden;
 }
 .search-txt{
    border:none;
    background: none;
    outline: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    transition: 0.4s;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 0px;  
 }
 /* responsive*/
 @media only screen and (max-width: 828px){
   .search-box:hover > .search-txt{
      width: 125px;
      }
 }
```

```html
 <body>
    <div class="search-box">
       <input class="search-txt" type="text" name="" placeholder="Type to search">
       <a class="search-btn" href="#">
           <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
       </a>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Html element

```
<div class="Card">
<div class="CardInner">
<label>Search for your stack :)</label>
<div class="container">
<div class="Icon">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24        24" fill="none" stroke="#657789" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-search"><circle cx="11" cy="11" r="8"/><line x1="21" y1="21" x2="16.65" y2="16.65"/></svg>
 </div>
<div class="InputContainer">
  <input placeholder="search here...."/>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS Element

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind&display=swap');

* {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  color: #acbdce;
}

:root {
  --border-radius: 10px;
}

body, html {
  background: #e2e9f4;
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template: 1fr/100%;
  place-items: center;
}

.Card {
  padding: 1px;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  background: linear-gradient(-67deg, rgba(#c8d8e7, .7), rgba(255,255,255,.8));
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 
    -2px -2px 6px rgba(#fff, .6),
    2px 2px 12px #c8d8e7;
  width: 380px;
}

.CardInner {
  padding: 16px 16px;
  background-color: #e2e9f4;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.Icon {
  min-width: 46px;
  min-height: 46px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  margin-right: 12px;
  box-shadow: 
    -2px -2px 6px rgba(#fff, .6),
    2px 2px 12px #c8d8e7;
    
  svg {
    transform: translate(-1px, -1px);    
  }
}

label {
  font-family: "Hind", sans-serif;
  display: block;
  color: #3c4b66;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(#6b7b8f, 1), #3c4b66);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.InputContainer {
  width: 100%;
}

input {
  background-color: #e3edf7;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  border: none;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #a9b8c9;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  transition: all 240ms ease-out;
  width: 100%;
  
  &::placeholder {
    color: #6d7f8f;
  }
  
  &:focus {
    outline: none;
    color: #6d7f8f;
    background-color: lighten(#e3edf7, 3%);
  }
};
  
.InputContainer {
  --top-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px #c5d4e3, inset 2px 2px 6px #c5d4e3;
  --bottom-shadow: inset -2px -2px 4px rgba(255,255,255, .7);
  
  position: relative;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  overflow: hidden;
  
  &:before,
  &:after {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    pointer-events: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
  }
  
  &:before {
    box-shadow: var(--bottom-shadow);
  }
  
  &:after {
    box-shadow: var(--top-shadow);
  }
}
```